Using 'de' versus 'sur'
How would you translate this string:
"Showing page 1 of 25 of 250 results"
de, sur, combination?

Is 5 the number of items in a page or the total number of results ?

Assuming it's page 1 of the first of the 5 results : "... affichant la page 1 du premier des 5 résultats".

What exactly do you mean? "Showing page 1 of 5",  "Showing 1 to 1 of 5 results" would be clear in English but I'm afraid what you write is rather strange. And people are asked to tell what they have found in their research before they ask a question, please visit the Help Centre.

If I had to re-state the English version, it would be "Page 1 of 25 out of a total of 250 results." This is what is meant above.

@AndreSostizzo Please update your question to include the correction (Click on Edit).

Do you mean that each page contains 10 results, i.e  page 1  showing  result 1 to 10, ..., page 25 showing result 226 to 250 ? Or that result #1 has 25 pages ?

250 résultats, sur 25 pages: page 1.

One may say:
"Page 1 sur 25, sur un total de 250 résultats"
But this seems a bit odd to my ears : it mixes pages and results.
I see no problem when saying "1 page sur 25" or "1 résultat sur 250"... but "Page 1 (...) sur 250 résultats" seems rather unprecise.
So I would prefer the following sentence:

Page 1 sur 25 (total : 250 résultats)

or even adding the size of the current page

Page 1 sur 25 (5 résultats sur 250)

